# Eclipse: How to close multiple windows

Tags: eclipse

Once you have a bunch (20+) source windows open in Eclipse is there way to close them with clicking all the close buttons on the tabs? It takes a long time and if you double click the middle button it maximises the window instead.

I guess worst case I'll learn to write a plugin that just closes them all, but ideally I want a little list box that I can easily close them in, like the buffer list in emacs or the window list in devstudio.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Right click one of the source tabs, then click "Close all".  This is in Eclipse 3.4, don't know what version it was first available in.

Comment: holy crap, that's embarrassingly obvious

Comment: LOL, I do the same thing from time to time with different programs.  "How do I do this??? Oh, yeah, right click, it shows a whole set of commands..."

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+W is the short cut key for close all.  Ctrl+w closes the current editor.

Comment: Or Ctrl+Shift+F4 for close all and Ctrl+F4 to close current

Answer (score 19):

Beside the "Close All" functionality kbrasee mentioned you can work with a "buffer list" using Window / Navigation / Switch to Editor (or Ctrl+Shift+E). In this dialog you can select multiple editors for saving / closing.

Comment: Also nice thanks. I couldn't find this option when browsing the window menu because I'm not in tune with Eclipse's terminology yet. To me, an editor is not a window, and "switch to editor" does not sound like a a way to manage a list of windows. Thanks again.

Comment: This was very helpful since my windows were hidden in some tab/collapsed menu I couldn't find.

Comment: I logged in just to upvote your answer! I have been looking for a way to close multiple open tabs/ editors, not all nor all except the one I am on, in Eclipse for so long now, I can't even remember. I wonder why there's no obvious way to do this yet. Thanks @Csaba_H for saving my future time!

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this is a little bit unrelated to your question but you can limit the number of open files by selecting "Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Number of opened editors before closing". If you set it to 8, opening the 9th file will close the file you visited most early.

Answer (score 7):

For a fast and selective solution you can click with the mouse wheel (yes!) into the middle of a tab you want to close. You don't have to target the close X.

Answer (score 0):

To close all your open files in Eclipse, simply goto **File** -> **Close all**

Answer (score 0):

First if you use the right click mouse on the tabs you can choose either Close All or Close Others.
Second you can press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`W` to close all the opened tabs.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to what mentioned by others,

If the undesired tabs are related to a project, you can right click the project name and choose close project, all its taps will be closed